# Cannot find linux images using describe_images() in boto3

Tags: python, boto3

Using boto3, when I filter images in describe_images(), with 'platform' as the name, I find filtered results only when I use 'windows' as it's value and when I try using linux or ubuntu, it doesn't appear to be working, how can I get linux images?

```
def describe_images(images, platform = ['windows'] image_type = ['machine'], architecture = ['x86_64'], owners = ['amazon'], root_device_type = ['instance-store']):#Not working when platform = ['linux']
global ec2

def describe(ec2):
    try:
        describe_img = ec2.describe_images(Filters = [{'Name' : 'platform', 'Values' : platform},{'Name' : 'image-type', 'Values' : image_type},{'Name' : 'architecture', 'Values' : architecture}, {'Name' : 'root-device-type', 'Values' : root_device_type}], Owners = owners, DryRun = False)
    except:
        raise
    else:
        for img in describe_img['Images']:
            #print('---img:',img)
            images.append(img['ImageId'])
            #print('---img[]:',img['ImageId'])
        print('len images:',len(images))
        print('---images:',images)
    
try:
    #print('describe images entered')
    describe_img = ec2.describe_images(DryRun = True)

except ClientError as e:
    #print('--if dry run op in e:','DryRunOperation' in str(e))
    if 'DryRunOperation' not in str(e):
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror(title = 'Error', message = 'It is found that the account doesn\'t have the permission(s) required to see the images. Please try again after obtaining the required permission(s).')
    elif 'DryRunOperation' in str(e):
        describe(ec2)
    else:
        raise
#print('leaving describe images.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `platform` option applies only to windows (from [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html)):

> This value is set to windows for Windows AMIs; otherwise, it is blank.

Thus to get linux images **don't use** `platform` filter.

However, at present I'm not sure if not using the filter will also include windows or not. If yes, then you either have to filter it out later, or use other option for filtering specific to linux images only.

Comment: By other option, do you mean using python in general or is there a solution provided by boto3 to get linux images, like windows images?

Comment: @LaNa Have you run without the `platform` filter? Maybe it already provides only linux images.

Comment: I found that while windows images have the keys 'Platform' and 'PlatformDetails', linux images has only the 'PlatformDetails'  key with linux/UNIX as value. This might be the reason for having only 'windows' as the value for the 'platform' filter.